# $S$-matrix element for real photon production

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, thermal-field-theory

In [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=00_x6GR8GXoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Thermal field theory by Bellac) on page 109 the $S$-matrix element for the transition from an initial state to a final state plus photon $(i)\to(f,\gamma)$ is given:

$$S_{fi}^{(\lambda)}(Q)=-ie\int d^4x e^{i Q\cdot x} \epsilon^{(\lambda)}_{\mu}(Q)<f|j^{\mu}(x)|i>$$
where $Q$ is the photon four momentum, $\epsilon^{(\lambda)}_{\mu} $ is its polarization four vector and $j_{\mu}$ is the electromagnetic current.

How can I derive this?

Comment: When you give a link to a book or paper it's best to state the title and author(s) so the question remains useful when/if [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) kills the link in the future.

Comment: Done. I included the title and author

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not know how to derive this, but I can convince you why this holds I think. The S-matrix element for the interaction $(i)\rightarrow(f,\gamma)$ would be written (according to your notation I think) as
$$<f,\gamma|S|i>$$
Given that $S=e^{i\int d^4x\mathcal{L}_I}$, where $\mathcal{L}_I$ is the interaction QED Lagrangian, $\mathcal{L}_I=-eA_{\mu}(x)j^{\mu}(x)$, where $j^{\mu}(x)$ is simply the matter current, and given that what we are looking there is just the first order in perturbation theory scattering amplitude, one can write the amplitude above as
$$<f,\gamma|S|i>=-ie\int d^4x<f|A_{\mu}(x)j^{\mu}(x)|i>$$
Now, one can expand the electromagnetic field according to
$$A_{\mu}(x)=A_{\mu}^{+}(x)+A_{\mu}^-(x)$$
where $A_{\mu}^{+}$ creates a photon at point $x$ in the final state and $A_{\mu}^{-}$ destroys a photon at point $x$ in the final state. So, if there is no other photon in the final state, the latter will not survive and the former will be written as a Fourier expansion containing the exponential factor $e^{iQ\cdot x}$, the operator that will create a photon in the final state and the polarization vector. Also, there is going to be an integral over the photon's momentum. From that point, one can define the S-matrix element in the momentum space to be everything but that last integral over the photon's momentum. There you have your expression ...

I hope that helps.